# I am using a collector node on IIB to collect messages. Can someone guide with sample ESQL after collector node to process a message collection?

Tags: file, websphere, blob, message, broker

I'm using the FileOutputNode to write the data into the file. I have tried writing the collection messages in the file but every time the file created is of 0 byte and there is no data.

```
    SET OutputRoot.Properties = InputRoot.Properties;
    CREATE FIELD OutputRoot.Collection.IN;
    DECLARE refCollection REFERENCE TO InputRoot.Collection.IN[1];
    WHILE LASTMOVE(refCollection) DO
        SET OutputRoot.Collection.IN= refCollection;
        SET i = i + 1;
        MOVE refCollection NEXTSIBLING REPEAT TYPE NAME;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN TRUE;
```

Comment: It's going to very difficult to answer your question properly without any code. Please can you supply a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code?

Comment: Added the code where I'm trying to copy the InputRoot to the OutputRoot.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to provide help without knowing what your input message tree looks like.

You should follow the instructions here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bc16130_.htm

If you need further help, you should

- add Trace nodes into your message flow before and after the Compute node and set the Pattern property on both nodes to ${Root}. This will allow you to see (and share) the structure of InputRoot and OutputRoot.
- Enable user trace using the console commands mqsichangetrace, mqsireadlog, mqsiformatlog. This will show you exactly what the message flow is doing. It will also contain the full text of any errors that are being reported.